# Asus K55V laptop not turning ON, what could be the reason

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure

ASUS Laptop K55VD is not starting.

When I press the Power button, all the Led indicators turn ON for 1 second, then it go OFF. CPU fan not spinning up, nothing on display. I have removed the battery, RAM, SSD,Keyboard, but same behavior.

Issue first appeared after I disassembled my Laptop recently. This occurred temporarily, 1 or 2 times and it was working(I thought if it was some loose connection in ribbon cables).

When I was using the Laptop(was using Photoshop, ie moderately CPU intense task), it immediately shut down and the problem became permanent, Laptop can't be started.
What could be the reason?

Comment: Perhaps dirty (fan clogged), then CPU overheated, then failed.  That is a possibility. By now you need to take it to a local shop for repair.

Comment: @John means I have to replace CPU?

Comment: That seems likely, or replace the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely had an overheating when running intensive tasks and that led to the damage one of the chips - chipset, video chip or CPU.
Most probably it was caused by poor mounting of the cooler after disassembling.

MB can be repaired or replaced in service center (chips can be replaced by soldering).